# How to add items to a ComboBox from a Excel sheet row?

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I'm new in the world of VBA macros. I'm trying to create a user form with several ComboBox in it. I know the method to an item one-by-one but I'm trying to add a whole row from another Excel sheet.

What I've tried :

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize() 'initialize the user form
    Dim lRow As Long
    Worksheets("Data").Activate
    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    ComboBox1.List = Sheets("Data").Range("B2:lRow").Value
End Sub
```

I've obtained with this, an execution error '1004'.

Does someone can help me? Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. Your syntax was slightly off. `Range("B2:lRow")` is not a valid range.

And you can avoid activating the sheet.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize() 'initialize the user form
    Dim lRow As Long

    With Worksheets("Data")
        lRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        ComboBox1.List = .Range("B2:B" & lRow).Value
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `ComboBox1.List = Sheets("Data").Range("B2:B" & lRow).Value`

Comment: It doesn't work, I obtain with this a new execution error '381' where the list is not well-defined.

Comment: This is one of those times when you do need to specify `.Value`, otherwise this is fine.

Comment: Thanks, I cut the extract a little short - edited - lesson learned